# Avoid .htaccess showing variables at the end of URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Im having a weird issue here; The following .htaccess works but now (after changing to a dedicated server) it just appends the variable at the end of the url at the browser's address bar; For example:

If I call this..
http://www.mydomain.com/sports

It gets rewrote like this.. :( 
http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?u=sports

I just want it to stay like exactly like it was called :)

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?u=$1 [NC]
```

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: I tried that, but it return a 400 Bad Request error :/

Comment: @Seybsen just the .htaccess, why?

Comment: Also, its adding a this to the end when called for www.mydomain.com:  http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?u=index.html.var and that "index.html.var" part idk where it comes from :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last rule should look like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?u=$1 [L,QSA]
```

> [QSA] - When the replacement URI contains a query string, the default
>   behavior of RewriteRule is to discard the existing query string, and
>   replace it with the newly generated one. Using the [QSA] flag causes
>   the query strings to be combined.
>
> [L] - The [L] flag causes mod_rewrite to stop processing the rule set.
>   In most contexts, this means that if the rule matches, no further
>   rules will be processed. This corresponds to the last command in Perl,
>   or the break command in C. Use this flag to indicate that the current
>   rule should be applied immediately without considering further rules.